# Defocus click event on map

Tags: carto, carto-js

I try building a map using CartoDB.js. The map displays a number of points. When a point is clicked, I change the layer SQL to filter some points out. What I want is that when user click on the map, outside of any point, I can handle this event to revert the map to initial state. Will it be possible?

Comment: Basically, yes, you can do pretty much everything with Javascript. But, it would help if you showed what you have tried so far.

Comment: I can see the events of layer and sublayer for "featureClick" but there is no event for something like on layerClick?